# Updated javascript files not being distributed by the server for several minutes after updating them

Tags: javascript, apache, tomcat, bluehost

I'm currently on a Bluehost shared hosting service, and for whatever reason my javascript files, upon change in the server's directories, will still be served as their old version until 10+ minutes passes. This is making development extremely slow and difficult. Is there any reason the server is doing this, and is there a way to disable whatever sort of caching is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check that it isn't your browser caching - in Chrome developer tools, you can disable caching. Perhaps also try a private window. If that still fails, the hosting service may have caching (would make sense for their business).

Cheap hack though - add a timestamp value as a query parameter for all script tags, eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js?t=12345" /><script>
```

how you accomplish this is up to what sever-side code you're using. The changed URL should defeat caching and won't affect the script.

Comment: Wow, the query param worked! Thanks for the quick fix :)

Comment: You're welcome. You'll need to set it via server-side code or update your HTML at every deployment - the URL with the query parameter is now cached too.

Comment: thats what I looking for